# How to fix this error?: Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation (code -26)

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, signature, sendrawtransaction

I'm trying to unlock money from P2SH ***2NG4PEU9rya1fcqAfSvQQAteaUkvc54J1fF***, but the library is not used by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2bw_N6kQL8

When I combine the Tx, I hash the Tx with SHA256 twice, then sign it with ECDSA (not used library).

After I verify that the signatures I have are valid and collect the signed tx (Signed Tx) and distribute the Tx to the bitcoin network (testnet), the problem I encounter is "Unacceptable signature: unnecessarily high S-value."

and then edit this thread.
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0146.mediawiki

After I did this method, the result of S is less than R, but there is another problem. "Signature must be zero for action. Failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG"

But Script it not multisig

But here is still a problem. So I don't know how to solve this problem. and don't know how to ask this question to the point

```
Private Key: 
| hex = 82d6cfc556c25e3fd02eb384bd95ba4fd217911836ce5b19fb34c864f6a5a9f4 
| dec = 59180209569427299317707189507794282735328653532808969125005524031929026193908 

Public Key: 
| x = 00aa36a1958e2fc5e5de75d05bcf6f3ccc0799be4905f4e418505dc6ab4422a8db
| y = 1fabeb6911ae2715032944ca90d452b30192b5539e4dfb0c386013321fcada8c

Unsigned Transaction: 
| 0100000001fc3adf56a9b345dd394479b5438365777ba7d91eb3954d9f2b5e2c7a68d06b980000000029030c3725b1752102aa36a1958e2fc5e5de75d05bcf6f3ccc0799be4905f4e418505dc6ab4422a8dbacfdffffff01d36f0300000000001600149058b7a55f5d5f88667a01fd66dd59e379002f5d0c372500

Message (doubleSHA256): 40a9f18c88d0f16989742b5fde90c52097c6c52feb37f7bf912140998b0713f4

Signatures: 
| r = 85481222987935817085579092069107947283118149501178124668858153032995539683302
| s = 23241719739309219792817770422392736282205653387772946202874350868806068363298

Signed Transaction: 
| 0100000001fc3adf56a9b345dd394479b5438365777ba7d91eb3954d9f2b5e2c7a68d06b980000000073483045022100bcfca85cc0582a456aefd52539747bf24342b360f821d66a570fb7b754b687e60220336258e21892cea41ea90a8a8538b0af4081c605f2f7a73821f871066c2060220129030c3725b1752102aa36a1958e2fc5e5de75d05bcf6f3ccc0799be4905f4e418505dc6ab4422a8dbacfdffffff01d36f0300000000001600149058b7a55f5d5f88667a01fd66dd59e379002f5d0c372500
```

```
{
  "txid": "53a4886fa2f89864c0b874b0db03836b4cbb1b9b13fa45d0ca262cf321138c5d",
  "hash": "53a4886fa2f89864c0b874b0db03836b4cbb1b9b13fa45d0ca262cf321138c5d",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 197,
  "vsize": 197,
  "weight": 788,
  "locktime": 2438924,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "986bd0687a2c5e2b9f4d95b31ed9a77b77658343b5794439dd45b3a956df3afc",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100bcfca85cc0582a456aefd52539747bf24342b360f821d66a570fb7b754b687e60220336258e21892cea41ea90a8a8538b0af4081c605f2f7a73821f871066c206022[ALL] 030c3725b1752102aa36a1958e2fc5e5de75d05bcf6f3ccc0799be4905f4e418505dc6ab4422a8dbac",
        "hex": "483045022100bcfca85cc0582a456aefd52539747bf24342b360f821d66a570fb7b754b687e60220336258e21892cea41ea90a8a8538b0af4081c605f2f7a73821f871066c2060220129030c3725b1752102aa36a1958e2fc5e5de75d05bcf6f3ccc0799be4905f4e418505dc6ab4422a8dbac"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967293
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00225235,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 9058b7a55f5d5f88667a01fd66dd59e379002f5d",
        "desc": "addr(tb1qjpvt0f2lt40csen6q87kdh2eudusqt6atkf5ca)#6fsn5mx5",
        "hex": "00149058b7a55f5d5f88667a01fd66dd59e379002f5d",
        "address": "tb1qjpvt0f2lt40csen6q87kdh2eudusqt6atkf5ca",
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

```
// jdk 20

object EllipticCurve {

    // * Secp256k1
    private val A = BigInteger.ZERO
    private val B = BigInteger.valueOf(7)
    private val P = BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F", 16)
    private val N = BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141", 16)
    private val G = Point(
        BigInteger("79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798", 16),
        BigInteger("483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8", 16)
    )

    // * จุดบนเส้นโค้งวงรี มีพิกัด x และ y
    data class Point(val x: BigInteger, val y: BigInteger)


    // ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── \\

    /*
    * < Elliptic Curve cryptography >
    * ในส่วนนี้เป็นการคำนวณค Public Key
    *
    * อ้างอิงจาก:
    * https://github.com/wobine/blackboard101/blob/master/EllipticCurvesPart5-TheMagic-SigningAndVerifying.py
    * */

    // * https://www.dcode.fr/modular-inverse
    fun modinv(A: BigInteger, N: BigInteger = P) = A.modInverse(N)


    fun doublePoint(point: Point): Point {
        val (x, y) = point

        // ! (3 * x * x + A) % P
        val slope = (BigInteger.valueOf(3) * x * x + A) % P

        val lam_denom = (BigInteger.valueOf(2) * y) % P

        val lam = (slope * modinv(lam_denom)) % P

        val xR = (lam * lam - BigInteger.valueOf(2) * x) % P

        val yR = (lam * (x - xR) - y) % P

        // * จุดใหม่ที่ได้หลังจากการคูณด้วย 2 บนเส้นโค้งวงรี
        return Point(xR, (yR + P) % P)
    }

    fun addPoint(point1: Point, point2: Point): Point {
        if (point1 == point2) {
            return doublePoint(point1)
        }
        val (x1, y1) = point1
        val (x2, y2) = point2

        val slope = ((y2 - y1) * modinv(x2 - x1)) % P

        val xR = (slope * slope - x1 - x2) % P

        val yR = (slope * (x1 - xR) - y1) % P

        // ! จัดการพิกัด Y ที่เป็นค่าลบ
        val yResult = if (yR < BigInteger.ZERO) yR + P else yR

        return Point(xR, yResult)
    }

    fun multiplyPoint(k: BigInteger, point: Point? = null): Point {
        // * ตัวแปร current ถูกกำหนดให้เป็น point ที่รับเข้ามา หากไม่มีการระบุ point ค่าเริ่มต้นจะเป็นจุด G ที่ใช้ในการคูณเช่นกับ private key
        val current = point ?: G

        // * แปลงจำนวนเต็ม k เป็นเลขฐานสอง
        val binary = k.toString(2)

        // * เริ่มต้นด้วยจุดเริ่มต้นปัจจุบัน
        var currentPoint = current

        // * วนลูปตามจำนวน binary digits ของ k
        for (i in 1 until binary.length) {
            currentPoint = doublePoint(currentPoint)

            // * ถ้า binary ตัวที่ตำแหน่ง i เป็น '1'  ให้บวกจุดเริ่มต้น (current) เข้ากับจุดปัจจุบัน (currentPoint)
            if (binary[i] == '1') {
                currentPoint = addPoint(currentPoint, current)
            }

            // * Debug
            //println("binary[i] = $i:")
            //println("Current Point: $currentPoint \n")
        }

        // * ส่งคืนจุดที่คำนวณได้
        return currentPoint
    }


    // ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── \\
    
 
 
 object ECDSA {

        /*
        * https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki
        */


        fun SignSignature(privateKey: BigInteger, message: BigInteger): Pair<BigInteger, BigInteger> {
            val m = message
            val k = BigInteger("42854675228720239947134362876390869888553449708741430898694136287991817016610")
            //val k = BigInteger(256, SecureRandom())

            val point = multiplyPoint(k)
            val kInv = modinv(k, N)

            val r: BigInteger = point.x % N
            var s: BigInteger = ((m + r * privateKey) * kInv) % N

            // * https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0146.mediawiki
            if (s > N / BigInteger.TWO) s = N - s else s

            return Pair(r, s)
        }

        fun VerifySignature(publicKeyPoint: Point, message: BigInteger, signature: Pair<BigInteger, BigInteger>): Boolean {
            val (r, s) = signature

            val w = modinv(s, N)
            val u1 = (message * w) % N
            val u2 = (r * w) % N

            val point1 = multiplyPoint(u1)
            val point2 = multiplyPoint(u2, publicKeyPoint)

            val point = addPoint(point1, point2)
            val x = point.x % N
            return x == r
        }

        // * https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0066.mediawiki
        fun toDERFormat(signature: Pair<BigInteger, BigInteger>): String {
            val (r, s) = signature
            val rb = r.toByteArray()
            val sb = s.toByteArray()

            val der_r = byteArrayOf(0x02.toByte()) + rb.size.toByte() + rb
            val der_s = byteArrayOf(0x02.toByte()) + sb.size.toByte() + sb
            val der_sig = byteArrayOf(0x30.toByte()) + (der_r.size + der_s.size).toByte() + der_r + der_s
            return der_sig.joinToString("") { String.format("%02x", it) }
        }

    }

    fun toDERFormat(signature: Pair<BigInteger, BigInteger>): String {
            val (r, s) = signature
            val rb = r.toByteArray()
            val sb = s.toByteArray()

            val der_r = byteArrayOf(0x02.toByte()) + rb.size.toByte() + rb
            val der_s = byteArrayOf(0x02.toByte()) + sb.size.toByte() + sb
            val der_sig = byteArrayOf(0x30.toByte()) + (der_r.size + der_s.size).toByte() + der_r + der_s
            return der_sig.joinToString("") { String.format("%02x", it) }
        }
    
}
```